# Why did Victor Hugo write that "the interior of the soul" is "grander than the sky"?

Tags: meaning, french-language, victor-hugo, les-miserables

> “There is one spectacle grander than the sea, that is the sky; there is one spectacle grander than the sky, that is the interior of the soul.”
>
> ― Victor Hugo, [*Les Misérables*](https://www.goodreads.com/work/quotes/3208463)

Whether "the interior of the soul" "is one spectacle grander than the sky" ― doesn't this depend on the soul and the morality of a person? Would Hugo's quotation still apply to evildoers?

I lit upon this quotation on p 261 in [*Spectacle: Rare and Astonishing Photographs*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/38395374-national-geographic-spectacle). [Goodreads quotes it too.](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/512939-there-is-one-spectacle-grander-than-the-sea-that-is)

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the totality of Hugo's quotation in French, it clearly encompasses evil-doers.

This is a misleading translation of a sentence taken out of context. They have translated the word [*grand*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/french-english/grand) (which means *big, great, tall* in French) as *grand*, which in English has positive connotations that the word does not have in French. And they have left off the previous sentences, which clarify Hugo's intent.

And I notice that [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/355803-the-mind-s-eye-can-nowhere-find-anything-more-dazzling-or) has a different quote which includes the previous sentences.

Here is my translation (aided by Google and Bing translate):

> Nowhere can the mind's eye find more radiance or more darkness than in man; it cannot gaze on anything that is more intimidating, more complicated, more mysterious, or more infinite. There is a spectacle greater than the sea, it is the sky; there is a spectacle greater than the sky, it is the interior of the soul.

And here is the original:

> L’œil de l’esprit ne peut trouver nulle part plus d’éblouissements ni plus de ténèbres que dans l’homme ; il ne peut se fixer sur aucune chose qui soit plus redoutable, plus compliquée, plus mystérieuse et plus infinie. Il y a un spectacle plus grand que la mer, c’est le ciel ; il y a un spectacle plus grand que le ciel, c’est l’intérieur de l’âme.

Comment: I add that even evildoers have this grandeur, because neither the sea nor the sky have the moral capacity to do evil.